# Dynamically adding html selects to form

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I have some javascript code that dynamically adds a pair of select elements to a form when the user clicks a button. The pattern that I am using right now for the naming convention is:

```
<select name="foo:1"/>
<select name="foo_quantity:1"/>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The next time the user clicks the button, another pair of selects are added

```
<select name="foo:2"/>
<select name="foo_quantity:2"/>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The 1 and 2 denote the index. Server side, it's a little cumbersome to try to match up the item/quantity. My question is, is there a better convention that I can use to make it easier on the server to match up the item/quantity? I'm using Spring MVC, so ideally, I would like the controller method to take in a List of LineItem objects, where a line item has an Id (foo) and some quantity.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<select name="foo"/>
<select name="foo_quantity"/>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
...
<select name="foo"/>
<select name="foo_quantity"/>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

or

```
<select name="foo[0]"/>
<select name="foo_quantity[0]"/>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
...
<select name="foo[1]"/>
<select name="foo_quantity[1]"/>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The first option works great with struts, im not sure about Spring MVC.

You could also use some form tags for Spring, you can find more information about here:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/